# TensorFlow Error Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 193 Please make sure cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll is in your library path

Tags: python, tensorflow

Same as Title
Have referred all the prev posts but none of them work
using following versions

tensorflow: 2,10
CUDAA : 11.5
cuDNN : 8.9.1

Tried Changing all versions but nothing seems to work
any guide or tutorial to install tensorflow to make it use gpu

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Build configurations are not exact. To install TensorFlow 2.10 with GPU support, you must have correct version of CUDA and cuDNN installed in your system which are CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1 and [set the path](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#build_using_the_msys_shell) for these softwares.

Please check the tested build configuration details below:
[image]

Please follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native_1) to install TensorFlow with GPU support by verifying all the mentioned Hardware and Software requirements as mentioned in the link.